# Acces Query runs smoothly in "select" mode, fails in "make table" mode

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Using 32-bit Access 2010 on a Windows 7 (64 bit windows) machine with 8-gigs of ram, I am trying to merge 2 tables into 1 using a `LEFT JOIN`

The first table contains ~5Mn (indexed with duplicates) records, the second table contains ~600K (no duplicates)

Basically the first table is my base table that i want to complement with information from fields available in the second table. I am doing a `LEFT JOIN` not an `INNER JOIN` because some entries in the large table have no matches in the smaller one, and I need them to show as blanks

When I run the query as a select query I get the exact desired outcome, when I try to save it by changing it to a `CREATE TABLE` query I get the error:

`Cannot open database. It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt`

I've looked around for solutions to this but they all point to corrupt files, but I feel I am missing something.

The query is:

```
SELECT [Key&Gov_LL_Bills].Accs_Meth_Num, [Key&Gov_LL_Bills].Acct_Num,
       [Key&Gov_LL_Bills].Bill_Stmt_Start_Dt, [Key&Gov_LL_Bills].Bill_Cycle_Id,          
       [Key&Gov_LL_Bills].Service_Chrg_Rev, [KA LL Active Services].NAME, 
       [KA LL Active Services].Party_Identification_Num, 
       [KA LL Active Services].Accs_Meth_Srv_Type_Name, 
       [KA LL Active Services].City_Name, 
       [KA LL Active Services].Accs_Meth_Srv_Type_Cd, 
       [KA LL Active Services].party_segment_type_cd 

       INTO test

       FROM [Key&Gov_LL_Bills] LEFT JOIN [KA LL Active Services] 
       ON 
       [Key&Gov_LL_Bills].Accs_Meth_Num = [KA LL Active Services].Accs_Meth_Num;"
```

Comment: The MetaSO post mentioned that the code to create a table was causing the post error. I edited one character of each sql command just to be sure they will not case the same error, and it worked. I am not sure which command was causing the error

Comment: NAME is a reserved keyword in Access, surround it with square brackets [NAME] to prevent any possible issues with this.

Comment: the real question is: why are you using microsoft access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research and trial and error, I was convinced this is a memory issue.

So if anyone is having the same problem, and does not have the time or resources to upgrade to 64 bit access or create and sql server, here is a pretty simple workaround.

Since the query runs in select mode, use vba to export the query result into a delimited `.txt` file, that you can read back into the original database, or a new database, as a table.

for anyone looking, the vba code to do that is very simple:

```
Sub exportQuery2Text()

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "", "mapProducts2Bills",_
"[filepath].txt", True

End Sub
```

I hope this is helpful

Cheers